# "ERROR: invalid transaction termination" when trying to execute a procedure with nested transaction control

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, commit, postgresql-11

According to the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), even with `AUTOCOMMIT` set to off, PSQL issues an implicit `BEGIN` just before any command that is not already in a transaction block and is not itself a `BEGIN` or other transaction-control command, nor a command that cannot be executed inside a transaction block such as `VACUUM`. (Unfortunately `CALL` is not treated in the same way as `VACCUM`). And, according to Shaun Thomas (https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/pg-phriday-stored-procedures-postgres-11/), the invalid transaction termination error happens because it is not possible to close the current transaction (in this case the one initiated by PSQL) from within the procedure. I have tried with all the PSQL settings related to transaction control, but the invalid transaction termination error occurs with all of them; even if the commands file processed by PSQL contains only the `CALL` statement.

This is the procedure I'm calling:

```
create or replace procedure producto$cargar_imagenes(_super$ bigint, _archivo$ character varying) as $$
declare
    _msg character varying;
    _log rastro_proceso%ROWTYPE;
begin
    perform rastro_proceso_temporal$insert(_super$);
    perform producto$cargar_imagenes$biz(_super$, _archivo$);
    if (_super$ is not null and _super$ > 0) then
        perform producto$cargar_imagenes$log(_super$, _archivo$);
    else
        perform tarea_usuario$private$update(6519204281880642486, null);
    end if;
    commit;
end;
$$ language plpgsql set search_path = public;
```

It fails at the `commit` statement; it works if I comment it out.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: please edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: "psql" is the PostgreSQL interactive terminal and not an acceptable abbreviation for Postgres. "Postgres" is. Or "pg" if you need it super short.

Comment: When I wrote PSQL I meant PSQL, I didn't mean Postgres.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `SET` clause. Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)

> If a SET clause is attached to a procedure, then that procedure cannot execute transaction control statements (for example, COMMIT and ROLLBACK, depending on the language).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the SET clause solves the problem.

Comment: @JorgeCampins when you remove SET, will it update the table?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that in pg11 (tested in version 11.6) you have the same problem if you include the "SECURITY DEFINER" clause in the procedure definition.  So I guess SECURITY DEFINER qualifies as a "SET" clause.

When I remove SECURITY DEFINER I can include a COMMIT statement within the procedure definition without getting the ERROR:invalid transaction termination on the COMMIT statement.

It is also unfortunate that this is a run time error, and NOT a compilation error.

Comment: To confirm your suspicion: "A SECURITY DEFINER procedure cannot execute transaction control statements" - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where procedure would process an update inside a plpgsql loop and then after update at commit would throw the error: "ERROR: invalid transaction termination" ... Finally tried turning on AutoCommit in PG Admin and procedure worked...for what its worth!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but i stumbled over this thread via google, because you used the word 'execute' in yout title. I ran into this issue because I called the procedure dynamically via `my_var = 'CALL prc_xyz();` and then `EXECUTE my_var INTO result_var;`. This aproach via `EXECUTE` cannot handle nested transaction control inside prc_xyz(). I hope this helps someone else.